# jQuery/CSS: Changing the height and width attributes of an image when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay

I'm working on a simple gallery built with HTML, CSS, and jQuery. When a user clicks on an image, a larger version of the image should pop up in a frame with an overlay behind it. 
I have no problems with horizontally-oriented images, but with vertically-oriented images, the larger image comes out distorted.

You can view my working sample on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/AXZgRV

I try to change the the attributes of the image by saving the height of the image in a variable and changing the attribute using jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be working.

How can I access the height and width of the larger image URL and put into the frame? I was trying the following code, which did not work.

```
var height_large = $(this).attr('height')

var width_large = $(this).attr('width')

$('#frame img').attr('height', height_large)
$('#frame img').attr('width', width_large)
```

For reference, here is the actual URL of the photo I'm trying to pull down:
https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7072/7274940170_c166072ddf_c.jpg

Comment: Please define "larger": do you want to scale the image up by a set percentage? Do you want to place an bounds on the maximum height/width? You get a distorted image now because you're scaling an image that starts at 200x200px up to 700x500px. You need to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: To get height of object you need to use "var height = $("img").height();", and to put new value "var height = $("img").height(newValue)";

Comment: I think you can just change the image source using `$('#frame img').attr('src', img_url);`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing height to auto for the #frame img worked for me.  It displays the larger image with your fixed width and accomodates the height accordingly. So it renders it proportionally correct. You'll just want to make sure that your images are at least as wide as that fixed width to start with to avoid upscaling.

```
#frame img {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -350px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the image's `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties after you set the `src` in the frame and set those values in the CSS's `width` and `height`. You should set a `load` event listener for the frame image so that it sets this as soon as the image finishes loading when you swap in the new `src`, as well as re-center the image by adjusting the `marginLeft` to half of the new image's width. You can also move the frame/overlay's fade effect into this so it fades into the correct size on click rather than it adjusting itself while fading in:

```
$('#frame img').on('load', function(e) {
  e.target.style.width = e.target.naturalWidth + 'px';
  e.target.style.height = e.target.naturalHeight + 'px';
  e.target.style.marginLeft = -(e.target.naturalWidth / 2) + 'px'; //re-center the image
  $(this).fadeIn(); 
  $('#overlay').fadeIn();
});
```